# How to edit unordered map from shared library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, unordered-map

I need to put a function-creator in unordered map. I'm trying to add a function like that:

mylib.cpp

```
std::unique_ptr<Strategy> makeAllDefect(){
    return std::make_unique<AllDefect>();
}


void g(Factory &a){
    a.addCreator("shared", makeAllDefect);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
Factory factory;

void load(){
    void (*g)(Factory &);
    void *handle = dlopen("libAllDefect.so", RTLD_NOW);

    if(!handle){
        std::cout << "Can't load library" << std::endl;
    }
    
    g = (void (*)(Factory&)) dlsym(handle, "g");
    std::cout << g;
    
    g(factory);

}
```

Library loads correctly, but dlsym always returns nullptr

Comment: please remove 'c' tag

Comment: How about read an output from `dlerror` after calling `dlsym`. And you are trying to get a `C` symbol of the C++ mangled function. Either compile the library with a `extern "C"` or use other methods of dynamic loading.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is `g()` function name from mylib.cpp is mangled by C++ compiler which means it would not have "g" name in the library but something like "_Z1gR7Factory". Simplest way to fix that is to declare `g()` having C linkage which will disable name mangling as well:

```
extern "C"
void g(Factory &a){
    a.addCreator("shared", makeAllDefect);
}
```

you can check what names you have in the library by `nm` utility in Linux or something like that.

For example I compiled following code:

```
struct Factory {};

extern "C"
void g( Factory & )
{
}
```

with and without `extern "C"` and here is nm output:

```
nm t.o
0000000000000000 T g

nm t.o
0000000000000000 T _Z1gR7Factory
```

When you declare pointer to function you want to make it `extern "C"` as well as theoretically it is possible that C++ and C functions may have different calling conventions (though I never heard about that in practice)